# Escape percent signs in given variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping, cmd

My first post, most questions already solved using this friendly provided knowldge here. But now I run out of ideas, again with a question about handling of poison characters in cmd.exe.

Let's assume there is a given string variable enclosed in double quotes. Most poison characters has already been replaced by common chars before, the left ones disturbing the script are "&", "(", ")" and "%". The string must be echoed to a file without quotes afterwards. So I had the idea to escape the poison characters tripled:

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SET AlbumArtist=%1
CALL :EscapePoisonChars %AlbumArtist% AlbumArtist_VDN

SET "FlacHyperLink==hyperlink^("file://%AlbumArtist_VDN%"^;"LossLess"^)")
echo %FlacHyperLink%
echo %AlbumArtist_VDN%

endlocal &GOTO:EOF

:EscapePoisonChars
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SET TmpString=%1
SET TmpString=%TmpString:&=^^^&%
SET TmpString=%TmpString:(=^^^(%
SET TmpString=%TmpString:)=^^^)%
endlocal&SET %2=%TmpString:~1,-1%&GOTO :EOF
```

When I call my script above I get the expected output - apart from the missing percent sign:

```
G:\YAET\20130204_Work>TryAmper.bat "100% Rock & Roll (7' UpMix)"
=hyperlink("file://100 Rock & Roll (7' UpMix)";"LossLess")
100 Rock & Roll (7' UpMix)

G:\YAET\20130204_Work>
```

I know that the percent can be escaped by itself. So "%%" will normally lead to a single literal "%". But it was not possible for me to find a working replace procedure for percent signs because cmd always interprets it as a variable and tries to expand it. Is this the complete wrong direction to handle this issue or just misunderstanding of variable expansion? Any hints welcome! Thanks!

Cheers, Martin

**Edit**
Removed own code, see below Jeb's answer for clean solution.

Thanks for help, Martin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice question!
At first, yes you can replace even percent signs, but not within a percent expansion, you need a delayed expansion here.

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set tmpstr=!tmpstr:%=%%!
```

But if you use the delayed expansion, you don't need the escapes anymore, as the delayed expansion is the last phase of the batch parser and all characters lose any special meaning.
You only need to echo with delayed expansion.

```
Echo !tmpvar!
```

**EDIT: Clean solution**

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

REM * More or less secure getting the parameter
SET "AlbumArtist=%~1"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "FlacHyperLink==hyperlink("file://!AlbumArtist!";"LossLess")"

echo !FlacHyperLink!
echo !FlacHyperLink!> hugo.txt
```

You need disableDelayedExpansion first, to get even exclamation marks from `%1`.
After that, you should switch to delayed expansion and use it anywhere.

Comment: Jeb, I hoped you will answer after I saw [link](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=4919#p4919) with your incredible hack I still do not understand completely. Finally your suggestion above solved my issue with poison characters. I added a short code snippet based on your solution to my question because I want to use code block format. Thanks a lot! Martin

Comment: Jeb, sorry if you're unhappy with my work. Using the code I encountered no problems for any combination of characters, so I thought it would be good enough to present the result here. I skipped it and just referred to your solution now. Martin

Comment: Hey, I know that this is an old post, but I'll try my luck here anyway. I'm trying to use this code to replace all occurrences of `%21` in a string to `!`, but nothing works.  You need delayed expansion (to properly process the `%22`) but then the documented escape for `!` which is `^^!` doesn't work inside a variable search/replace expression :/  Do you have a solution?

Comment: @Rahul2001 You should open a new question for this, as the answer needs some explanations