# Replace string % with %% using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a text like below in **input.txt** file.

```
sdf%5Ddfssdsd%2Ddfdf
```

I would like to replace "%" with "%%" in the output file. so the text should look like

```
sdf%%5Ddfssdsd%%2Ddfdf
```

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718591/escape-percent-signs-in-given-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%i in (input.txt) do (
  set _line=%%i
  set _line=!_line:%%=%%%%!
  echo !_line! >> output.txt
)

endlocal
```