# How to replace with percent character in cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, replace, cmd, escaping

In the Windows command prompt, I am trying to replace the space in `set string=Hello World` with the string `%20`. Naively trying to use the string literal %20 like this:

```
set string=%string: =%20%
```

results in `HelloWorld20%`. Trying to use the escape character `^` like this:

```
set string=%string: =^%20%
```

also results in `HelloWorld20%`. Trying to escape the `%` by doubling it like this:

```
set string=%string: =%%20%
```

results in `HelloWorld%20%`. I also tried to use another variable to do the replacement like this:

```
set r=%20
set string=%string: =%r%%
```

which results in `HelloWorldr%%`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718591/escape-percent-signs-in-given-variables), which handles the escaping of percent characters in variables. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296162/escaping-special-characters-in-cmd), which handles the escaped input of percent characters. But neither one seems to apply to string replacing.

A [tutorial/docu page for the Windows cmd.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) which I found online tells me I have the correct syntax, but does not cover replacing with percent characters.

After reading all of those, I tried:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set string=!string: =%20!
```

which results in `!string: =%20!`.

I am out of ideas, can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `delayed expansion` in this case:

```
set "str1=Hello World!"
set "str2=%20"
for /f "delims=" %a in ('cmd /v:on /c @echo "%str1: =!str2!%"') do set "str3=%~a"
echo %str3%
```

[What is delayed expansion?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx)

Comment: That results in `Hello!str2!World!`. Remember: I am doing this in cmd.exe not from a `.bat` file

Comment: Absolute lifesaver. Would you mind commenting the example, as the `for()` is a little bit black-magic. P.S. for those who want to do it in a batch script, there is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772456/string-replacement-in-batch-file.